# Преобразование string в int

Tags: php

Мне нужно преобразовать `string` в `int`. Код такой:

```
$balance = "0";
$bonus = "50";
echo (int)$balance+(int)$bonus;
```

Казалось, вывод должен быть `50`, но почему-то выводится `0`. Покопался в коде и выяснилось, что при преобразовании `$bonus` в `int` получается `0`.
Т.е.

```
$bonus == "50";
```

Но

```
(int)$bonus == 0
```

Версия PHP 5.4
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю?

Comment: 50 в ответ выводит, чего-то у вас не верно работает ;) Даже так `echo $balance+$bonus;` 50 будет выводить :Р

Comment: даже так `echo (int)($balance+$bonus);` тоже будет выводить 50 8-)

Comment: Видимо реальный код у вас другой. Здесь вы написали работающий код. Может у вас в реальности *опечатка в имени переменной*, поэтому она "пустая"?

Comment: Автор, попробуйте так - `$balance = 0; $bonus = 50;`. Так вы объявите `$balans` и `$bonus` не `string`, а `integer`. Может, ваш сервер `$balance = "0";` понимает как, например `$balance = "abc";` и делает из строки `integer`(что маловероятно).

Comment: Этот код всегда будет возвращать число, даже без ручного преобразования типов, пыха сама это сделает, скорее всего вы код не весь выложили

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код всегда будет выдавать `50` т.к. для PHP `+` это математический оператор и он всегда будет приводить к инту все слагаемые.
Вот апрув – http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c07685c5d4bf70e0785a6dea3d1f609802da425

В вашем случае скорее всего между объявлением переменных и их сложением где-то они либо удаляются, либо изменяются, либо у вас опечатка в коде и php приводит `null` к `0`. Последнюю ошибку можно словить если смотреть в логах ошибку  `E_NOTICE – Undefined variable`